Determinant of matrix, that has non-zero entries only in the first row, first column and the diagonal
Given are constants $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in\mathbb{R}$, $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n>0$ and the matrix
$$
M:=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \alpha_1 & \ldots & \alpha_n \\
\alpha_1 & \beta_1 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
\alpha_n & 0 &0 &\beta_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I find that $\det M = -\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} \alpha^2_{\sigma(1)}\beta_{\sigma(2)}\cdot\ldots\cdot\beta_{\sigma(n)}$. Is this correct?
I calculated along the first column and then along the first row:
\begin{align*}
\det M = \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^j\alpha_j\det(M_{(j,1)})
&
=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^j\alpha_j\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\alpha_k\det((M_{(j,1)})_{(1,k)})
\\
&=-\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j^2\beta_1\ldots\hat{\beta}_j\ldots\beta_n
\end{align*}
$M_{i,j}$ denotes the matrix you get, when erasing the $i$-th row and $j$-th column, and $\beta_1\ldots\hat{\beta}_j\ldots\beta_n$ the multiplication of all $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$ except for $\beta_j$.

your matrix is symmetric mostly zero... It is quite easy to congruence diagonalize. Call your matrix $M_0.$  One step at a time, let $M_{j+1} = E_j^T M_j E_j,$  where each $E_j$  is the identity matrix but with a single off-diagonal entry  nonzero. Try it for your $n=2$ and $n=3.$   Oh, $\det E_j = 1,$ so the determinant stays the same

Illustrations. I moved your first row/column to the last row/column. This is the result of multiplying your matrix on the right and left by a permutation matrix  that just transposes $1$   and $n$
In this order it is clear how to construct  my matrix $P$   upper triangular, determinant 1,  such that the outcome diagonal $D$  preserves the original nonzero diagonal elements.
A bit different in your original order. Comes out $P$ is lower diagonal, all $1$ on the diagonal and then appropriate ratios in the  rest of the first column  only
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
7 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 5 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
7 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 27 }{ 35 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 13 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
13 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 7 & 2 \\ 
5 & 3 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 11 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
13 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 11 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 7 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3316 }{ 1001 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
In your original order and with symbols:
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & -  \frac{ a }{ c } & -  \frac{ b }{ d } \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 0  & 0  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & a & b \\ 
a & c & 0 \\ 
b & 0 & d \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  0  \\ 
-  \frac{ a }{ c } & 1 &  0  \\ 
-  \frac{ b }{ d }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
-\frac{a^2}{c} -\frac{b^2}{d} & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & c & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & d    \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
